# Rails :dependent => :destroy VS :dependent => :delete_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

In rails guides it's described like this:

> Objects will be in addition destroyed if they’re associated with `:dependent => :destroy`, and deleted if they’re associated with `:dependent => :delete_all`

Right, cool. But what's the difference between being destroyed and being deleted?
I tried both and it seems to do the same thing.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

The difference is with the callback.

The `:delete_all` is made directly in your application and deletes by SQL :

```
DELETE * FROM users where compagny_id = XXXX
```

With the `:destroy`, there is an instantiation of all of your children. So, if you can't destroy it or if each has their own `:dependent`, its callbacks can be called.

Comment: The instantiation and the calling of destroy on each of the children objects will be slow if you have a lot of children (and n^2 if you have grandchildren, and so on). delete_all is the kind of "nuke it from orbit" solution where you don't care about / don't have any before / after destroy callbacks on the models.

Answer (score 139):

On a Rails' model association you can specify the `:dependent` option, which can take one of the following three forms:

- `:destroy/:destroy_all` The associated objects are destroyed alongside this object by calling their `destroy` method
- `:delete/:delete_all` All associated objects are destroyed immediately without calling their `:destroy` method
- `:nullify` All associated objects' foreign keys are set to `NULL` without calling their `save` callbacks

Comment: See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html (search for "nullify") for the authoritative rdocs.

Comment: Since Rails 3.0 it's also possible to specify `:restrict`. _If set to :restrict this object cannot be deleted if it has any associated object._

Comment: there's no `:delete` or `:destroy_all` options by the looks of it? _The :dependent option expects either :destroy, :delete_all, :nullify or :restrict (:delete)_

Comment: @MikeCampbell, `:delete` and `:destroy_all` options do not exist. However, there are class methods on models that are called `delete` and `destroy_all` so it might be the reason for confusion.

Comment: @MikeCampbell You are missing few more options, See  The :dependent option must be one of [:destroy, :delete_all, :nullify, :restrict_with_error, :restrict_with_exception]

Answer (score 38):

See **destroy deletes its associated elements**  where **delete_all can delete multiple data from self table** as `DELETE * FROM table where field = 'xyz'`

**:Dependent possible options:**

Controls what happens to the associated objects when their owner is destroyed. Note that these are implemented as callbacks, and Rails executes callbacks in order. Therefore, other similar callbacks may affect the :dependent behavior, and the `:dependent` behavior may affect other callbacks.

`:destroy` causes all the associated objects to also be destroyed.

`:delete_all` causes all the associated objects to be deleted directly from the database (so callbacks will not be executed).

`:nullify` causes the foreign keys to be set to NULL. Callbacks are not executed.

`:restrict_with_exception` causes an exception to be raised if there are any associated records.

`:restrict_with_error` causes an error to be added to the owner if there are any associated objects.

If using with the `:through` option, the association on the join model must be a belongs_to, and the records which get deleted are the join records, rather than the associated records.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the main difference is that any callbacks will not be invoked when `:delete_all` was used. But when used `:destroy` the callbacks stack (`:after_destroy`, `:after_commit` ...) will be fired.

Consequently, if you have `touch:`ing declarations in models being deleted then it's better to use `dependent: :delete_all` rather 'dependent: :destroy'.