# delete_all vs destroy_all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I am looking for the best approach to delete records from a table. For instance, I have a user whose user ID is across many tables. I want to delete this user and every record that has his ID in all tables.

```
u = User.find_by_name('JohnBoy')
u.usage_indexes.destroy_all
u.sources.destroy_all
u.user_stats.destroy_all
u.delete
```

This works and removes all references of the user from all tables, but I heard that `destroy_all` was very process heavy, so I tried `delete_all`. It only removes the user from his own user table and the `id` from all the other tables are made null, but leaves the records intact in them. Can someone share what the correct process is for performing a task like this?

I see that `destroy_all` calls the `destroy` function on all associated objects but I just want to confirm the correct approach.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

You are right. If you want to delete the User and all associated objects -> `destroy_all`
However, if you just want to delete the User without suppressing all associated objects -> `delete_all`

According to this post : [Rails :dependent => :destroy VS :dependent => :delete_all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797339/rails-dependent-destroy-vs-dependent-delete-all)

- `destroy` / `destroy_all`: The associated objects are destroyed alongside this object by calling their destroy method
- `delete` / `delete_all`: All associated objects are destroyed immediately without calling their :destroy method

Comment: It should also be noted that 1) Callbacks are not called when using `delete_all`, and 2) `destroy_all` instantiates all the records and destroys them one at a time, so with a very large dataset, this could be painfully slow.

Comment: suppose i'm running a before_destroy method in the model - if i use delete_all then this method won't run? secondly if i employ a before_delete method in my model, will this run when i run delete or delete_all in the rails console?

Answer (score 30):

delete_all is a single SQL DELETE statement and nothing more. destroy_all calls destroy() on all matching results of :conditions (if you have one) which could be at least NUM_OF_RESULTS SQL statements.

If you have to do something drastic such as destroy_all() on large dataset, I would probably not do it from the app and handle it manually with care.  If the dataset is small enough, you wouldn't hurt as much.

Answer (score 17):

To avoid the fact that `destroy_all` instantiates all the records and destroys them one at a time, you can use it directly from the model class.

So instead of :

```
u = User.find_by_name('JohnBoy')
u.usage_indexes.destroy_all
```

You can do :

```
u = User.find_by_name('JohnBoy')
UsageIndex.destroy_all "user_id = #{u.id}"
```

The result is one query to destroy all the associated records

Comment: Will it call the destroy callbacks on associated records, or is `UsageIndex.destroy_all` equivalent with `UsageIntex.delete_all` ?

Comment: `UsageIndex.destroy_all` is no longer available since rails 3

Answer (score 1):

I’ve made a [small gem](https://github.com/janosch-x/delete_recursively) that can alleviate the need to manually delete associated records in some circumstances.

> This gem adds a new option for ActiveRecord associations:
>
> dependent: :delete_recursively
>
> When you destroy a record, all records that are associated using this option will be deleted recursively (i.e. across models), without instantiating any of them.
>
> Note that, just like dependent: :delete or dependent: :delete_all, this new option does not trigger the around/before/after_destroy callbacks of the dependent records.
>
> However, it is possible to have dependent: :destroy associations anywhere within a chain of models that are otherwise associated with dependent: :delete_recursively. The :destroy option will work normally anywhere up or down the line, instantiating and destroying all relevant records and thus also triggering their callbacks.

Comment: This is fantastic! I wonder why not more people have watched/starred/forked it on github.. is it still working well?

Comment: @Magne Thanks! It should be working. The tests run on Ruby 2.4.1 and Rails 5.1.1. So far I've only used it privately and not in major production apps, hence the major version "0", but I never noticed any issues. It's also fairly simple, so it should be fine.

Comment: Cool. :) I am running a project on Ruby 2.3.1, and 'rails', '~>4.1.14', and am sadly forced to rely on activerecord (~> 4.1.0) due to other gems. I see that delete_recursively is resolved to 0.9.0. Is there an older version of it that would work with activerecord 4.1 ? I couldn't find any in the releases tab on github.

Comment: @Magne I found it actually [works for activerecord as low as 4.1.14](https://travis-ci.org/janosch-x/delete_recursively/builds/232587427) and have released gem version 1.0.0 with a relaxed dependency. Keep in mind that Rails' 4.1 branch no longer receives security updates, though.