# How to Destroy multiple objects simultaneously in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails application that is trying to delete multiple objects at a time.

I have tried like sending set of id seperated by ',' to rails destroy method,but it destroy only single object.
Is it possible to delete multiple objects in rails 3.

Comment: The answer has given is correct, but just for knowledge go through the difference of delete_all and destroy_all. This would help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698207/delete-all-vs-destroy-all

Answer (score 129, accepted):

**destroy_all** destroys the records matching conditions by calling **destroy method** for each  instantiating record. So object’s callbacks are executed.

```
Model.destroy_all(:status => "inactive")
Model.where(:id => [1,2,3,4,5]).destroy_all
Model.where(:id => 1..5).destroy_all
```

**UPDATE**

```
User.where(:id => params[:ids]).destroy_all

/users?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3
```

Comment: how to pass array of id , i tried like http://localhost:3000/users/id=[1,2,3,4]....Does rails accept this routes...

Comment: can you snow routes.rb file?

Answer (score 8):

```
Model.delete([1,2,5,6])
```

or

```
Model.delete_all(["col_name in (?)", [1,2,5,6]])
```

Just pass the ids array

Comment: delete is not the same thing as destroy.

Comment: How to pass array of ids ... i am getting a routing error when i tried like above...

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem, but the solution here did not work for me in rails 5.1.6.

Perhaps you pass parameter `params[:ids]` in the wrong way.

Here's how I fix it.

### Before

```
Model.where(:id => params[:ids]).destroy_all
```

### After

```
ids = params[:ids].split(",")
Model.where(:id => ids).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance is important to you and/or if you work on a large dataset you should prefer delete_all over destroy_all.

Destroy_all will execute a DELETE query one at a time. So it can be very slow. More details about the differences between delete_all and destroy_all can be found [on this page](http://blog.revathskumar.com/2012/04/ruby-activerecord-difference-between.html).

Since the @M Kumar's answer will be deprecated with the new rail's version.

```
Model.delete_all(["col_name in (?)", [1,2,5,6]])
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing conditions to delete_all is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1.
```

This command might help other's in the future :

```
Model.where(id: [1,2,5,6]).delete_all
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also delete for a range of Ids. Say you have 1500 records and you want to delete from 751 to last:

```
a = Model.where(id: [751..1500])
a.destroy_all
```