# Wait for fetch request to finish before running the next method in React?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, request, fetch

I am running Rails on backend and React on frontend. I have created a function that utilizes `fetch` method so React can talk to Rails - this function sends a `POST` request to Rails.

Ideally, I would like the following:

```
(1. GET all scores from rails API) -> (2. save them as states) -> (3. From React, perform POST/ PUT/ DELETE to Rails) -> (4. GET all updated scores from rails API) -> (5. save them as states) -> (&c.)
```

Ideally, I would like step `(3)` to completely finish before `(4)` executes, that way if I `POST` a new score on React to Rails, step `4` would fetch and GET the **new** score and my states will be up-to-date.

My problem is, sometimes step `(4)` would happen before step `(3)` even finishes. I said sometimes because sometimes it would update the states when I created/ deleted new score, and sometimes it would *not* update the states when I created/ deleted a new score.

Currently my function looks like this:

```
handleDelete(){
  ...
  Client.deleteScores(maxWeek).then(this.getStudentsAndScores());
}

#deleteScores:
function deleteScores(week){
  return fetch(`delete_latest_week`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      week: week
    })
  });
}

#scores_controller (rails):
def delete_by_week
  Score.destroy_all(:week => params[:week])
  head :no_content
end
```

*It says delete while it shows method POST. Long story short, it is deleting posts via POST method. Detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224342/how-to-send-fetch-request-to-perform-rails-destroy-all/45224533?noredirect=1#comment77416706_45224533). The gist of it is, I have a fetch `POST` method that need to be finished before React does something else.*

The `then` function, `getStudentsAndScores()` is the function that fetches GET data from Rails. I want it to wait for `Client.deleteScores()` to finish first before GETting the data, but it seems like `getStudentsAndScores` ran before it finished with `deleteScores()`. In short, after I deleted it, when it does not work, I have to **refresh** the page to see that it has been deleted.

How can I tell React to wait until it finishes with first request before executing the next function?

Answer (score 1):

The fetch call returns a promise. So, inside then you should not immediately call another function but rather provide a function which should be called when the promise resolves successfully. Try something like this -

```
handleDelete(){
  ...
  Client.deleteScores(maxWeek).then(this.getStudentsAndScores);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Akhil, thanks for the response! I have tried this already. I have it up there on the second line of the code I put up `Client.deleteScores(maxWeek).then(this.getStudentsAndScores());`

Comment: Hi, remove the parenthesis after your getStudentsAndScores function. It should just be Client.deleteScores(maxWeek).then(this.getStudentsAndScores);