# Rails: Delete associated records on object destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models

```
 class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :couponizations, dependent: :destroy     
   has_many :coupon_codes, through: :couponizations, source: :coupon_code, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :coupon_codes, allow_destroy: true
 end
```

and

```
class CouponCode < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :couponization, dependent: :destroy
   has_one :deal, through: :couponization, source: :deal
```

which are linked by many-to-many relationship

```
class Couponization < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :coupon_code
   belongs_to :deal
end
```

Despite I specified `dependent: :destroy` option, when I delete deal, coupon codes are not being deleted. However couponizations are deleted successfully. Is there any way to delete associated nested records on object destroy?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The options `dependent: :destroy` is ignored when using with the `:through` (see [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)). You have to do it manually, with a `after_destroy` [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) for example.

```
 class Deal

   after_destroy :destroy_coupon_codes

   private

   def destroy_coupon_codes
     self.coupon_codes.destroy_all   
   end
 end
```

Comment: does this atomic. it means if deleting fails, delete children will be recover again. thanks.

Comment: When deleting a file attachment field (in my case, based on Refile), use destroy_all instead of delete_all; If you don't use destroy_all, the physical file might not be deleted (I was using S3, and had this issue). See discussion on difference between delete_all and destroy_all here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698207/delete-all-vs-destroy-all

Answer (score 8):

I recommend using `:after_destroy` callback, so if destroying some `Deal` instance fails for whatever reason you don't end up deleting all of its `CouponCodes`.

Here's an `:after_destroy` example that should work:

```
after_destroy { |record|
  CouponCode.destroy(record.coupon_codes.pluck(:id))
}
```

Make sure to remove `dependent: :destroy` from `has_many :couponizations` in the `Deals` model, because all `couponizations` will now be destroyed by the `has_one :couponization, dependent: :destroy` in the `CouponCode` model.