# Destroy all records associated with object in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a database of movies and their associated genres.

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movie_genres
  has_many :movies, through: :movie_genres, dependent: delete_all
  before_destroy :delete_movie

  private

  def delete_movie
    self.movies.delete_all
  end

end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movie_genres
  has_many :genres, through: :movie_genres
end
```

My aim is that when a genre gets deletes - all of its movies also get deleted, regardless of if that movie has another genre or not. I've tried attaching dependent: :destroy to the Genre model however only the join table records get deleted. I've also tried using the before_destroy callback to delete the movies prior to deleting the genre however that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: What do you mean with "only the join table records get deleted?"

Comment: what exactly happens when you use delete_movie, in which way does it not work? Is the method called? Does it generates SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try `:destroy_all`. 
`destroy_all` will remove this and all associated objects. For large data, this can be slow though. 
Also See: [delete_all vs destroy_all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698207/delete-all-vs-destroy-all)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to select the records where the column is applicable and then call `destroy_all` on them. Am I missing something?

```
Movie.where(movie_genre: @movie.movie_genre).destroy_all
```