# Rails console confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

I'm trying to delete more that just one id. I'm currently using `Person.find(1).destroy`.

Is there a way that I can select more than just one data record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can write scripts in the console.

```
Person.find_each do |person|
  if # condition for deleting
    person.destroy
  end
end
```

Alternatively, if you know all the ids...you can use a where clause and then destroy all of them.

```
ids = [1,2,3,4,5]

people = Person.where(id: ids) # where can take an array of ids
people.each { |person| person.destroy }
```

Comment: You can also call `Person.where(id: [1,2,3]).destroy_all` and `delete_all` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698207/delete-all-vs-destroy-all for more info)