# delete_all does not work while each do delete does

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Intended functionality - delete all linked asset_items when an asset_line_item is deleted. (without using destroy, destroy_all). I am using postgres

With the following model:

```
class AssetLineItem < PurchaseLineItem

  has_many :asset_items
  ...

  after_destroy :destroy_cleanup

  private

  def destroy_cleanup
    asset_items.delete_all
  end
end
```

This results in the asset_items remaining, however all of their asset_line_item columns are set to null.

```
  def destroy_cleanup
    asset_items.each do |asset_item|
      asset_item.delete
    end
  end
```

replacing delete_all with the loop above however has the intended result of delete all associated asset_items.

Although I have working code, I'm curious what could cause delete_all to act in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling just `delete_all` on association just nullifies the reference. It is the same as `delete_all(:nullify)`:

```
pry(main)> Booking.last.passengers.delete_all
  Booking Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `bookings`.* FROM `bookings`  ORDER BY `bookings`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  SQL (2.8ms)  UPDATE `passengers` SET `passengers`.`booking_id` = NULL WHERE `passengers`.`booking_id` = 157
=> nil
```

You need to call `delete_all(:delete_all)` to actually delete associated records.

Here is [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionAssociation/delete_all).

Or to get desired effect you can add following line to your AssetLineItem model:

```
has_many :asset_items, dependent: :destroy
```

as **lakhvir kumar** mentioned.

Also your `destroy_cleanup` callback could be refactored to:

```
  def destroy_cleanup
    asset_items.map(&:delete)
  end
```

Here is some good links to the topic:

[delete_all vs destroy_all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698207/delete-all-vs-destroy-all)

[Rails :dependent => :destroy VS :dependent => :delete_all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797339/rails-dependent-destroy-vs-dependent-delete-all)

Comment: I needed the functionality of delete so i had to look past destroy. dependent: :delete_all actually works though. I suppose i am just confused why using dependent: :delete_all has a different result from calling asset_items.delete_all. When calls i think would be the same have different results i worry i have an underlying problem somewhere.
This is the correct answer though - it tells me why my delete_all call was just nulling the reference. i was not aware of delete_all(:delete_all) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

use `has_many :asset_items dependent: :destroy`