# Is there any method to disable after_find only in some cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, callback

I am using after_find in my model, but wanted to disable in in some cases.
And i am using **.where** still after_find is running but in document its said that it works only for following methods. Why is it so?

```
all
first
find
find_by
find_by_*
find_by_*!
find_by_sql
last
```

my api(grape framework) is

```
delete '/delete_user' do
  user_id = params[:user_id] #authenticate_current_user!
  @user_profile = ::UserProfile.where(user_id: user_id).
  @user_profile.destroy_all
end
```

Comment: Which document did you get that information from? The [rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) says: *"an `after_find` and `after_initialize` callback is triggered for each object that is found and instantiated by a finder"*. And the `find_by_*` methods were deprecated/moved out of core rails since v4, and removed completely in rails 5.

Comment: Can you please show your code? What do you mean by "disable in some cases"? There is likely a cleaner solution to your problem that does not involve `after_find` at all.

Comment: Saw in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html . Has added the code also.

Comment: Can you describe in natural language when do you want NOT to fire this callback?

Comment: Saw "The after_find callback will be called whenever Active Record loads A RECORD from the database. after_find is called before after_initialize if both are defined." this also in documentation. I doubt if its applicable to where clause as it written A RECORD in it.

Comment: I wanted to disable when this api in this question is called.

Comment: @shahanahamza Can you please show **all** relevant code, and properly describe what you are trying to achieve? I'm very reluctant to provide a (potentially poor/misleading) answer to a question that hasn't been properly explained. What have you currently written in `after_find`? Why have you done that? Why do you want to bypass that here? There are all sorts of solutions that may be a better fit for your problem, but I can't really suggest something without knowing what the problem **is**.

Answer (score 1):

The `after_find` callback is not being invoked by your `where` call; it is being invoked by your `destroy_all` call. `destroy_all` will instantiate each `UserProfile` object (and its associated objects) and call its `destroy` method, one-by-one.

If you want to delete all the `UserProfile` objects immediately, without instantiating them (and skipping **all** callbacks), then you can call:

```
UserProfile.where(user_id: user_id).delete_all
```

More information on the differences between [`destroy_all` and `delete_all`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698207/delete-all-vs-destroy-all) can be found in other answers on StackOverflow, but the differences that you care about are:

1. it will not instantiate the record
2. it will not delete associated objects
3. it will not invoke any callbacks

I would recommend that you not use `after_find` the way you are using it. There are [lots of ways to skip callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632742/how-can-i-avoid-running-activerecord-callbacks) but [almost nobody uses `after_find`](https://github.com/search?l=Ruby&q=after_find&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93). (compared to [`after_create`](https://github.com/search?l=Ruby&q=after_create&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93), for example)

The options for skipping `after_find` callbacks are limited. There are no [built-in Rails methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks) for doing so. (except as described above) If you absolutely have to keep the callback, then your best bet is to add a conditional to the callback definition:

```
after_find :foo, if: -> { <some logic> }
```

If you use a conditional like that then you have to start thinking about how that variable is read and set in a multithreaded environment, and how do you handle concurrent requests without creating a race condition, and it sends you down an ugly path that is better handled by not using `after_find` in the way you've described.

Comment: No. when i tried in my console, using **where**  clause, after_find is getting invoked. For ex: User.where(id: 2) invokes after_find method.

Comment: @shahanahamza That is only because you are running it in the console. If you run `UserProfile.where` in the console then `irb` will instantiate each record so it can conveniently display them for you. When `irb` instantiates the record the `after_find` callback is triggered. This *only* happens because the console is instantiating the records to show them.