# Rails: Delete records created before adding dependant: :destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any efficient way to delete all associated records which where created before adding dependant: :destroy ??

```
Class User
end

Class Post
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Previous records which were created before adding this dependent: :destroy are still present and have user_id present.
eg.

```
Post.first.user_id = 1
```

But User.first which has id of 1 is already destroyed before adding the dependent: : destroy.
How do i find and delete these Post records???

Comment: `Post.where.not(user_id: User.select(:id))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Post.where("NOT EXISTS(select 1 from #{User.table_name} where #{Post.table_name}.user_id=#{User.table_name}.id)").delete_all
```

This should delete all the posts whose associated user no longer exists in the db.
If you want to trigger the callbacks for each Post before deleting them use destroy_all instead.

See: [delete_all vs destroy_all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698207/delete-all-vs-destroy-all) for the difference.