# Active Record - Delete all dependent values only if its present in child table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am working in an Rails app, i am aware of `:dependent => delete_all` functionality in a Model.

Consider the below example

```
class TableA < ActiveRecord::Base 

    has_many :tablebs, :dependent => :delete_all

end


class TableB < ActiveRecord::Base 

    belongs_to :tablea

end
```

If there is corresponding foreign key reference in TableB which represents TableA,
then deleting record in TableA using Active record will delete all the corresponding 
rows in TableB.

But when there is no corresponding values in TableB, it shows like

`uninitialized constant TableA::TableB`

What i am trying to achieve is, the Active Record should delete dependent values if its present and
ignore the step if there is no dependent values.

Is this possible?

thanks,
Balan

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the fact that `belongs_to` must be related to a table in the singular. So, change the `tableas` for `tablea` as below:

I also suggest you to look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797339/rails-dependent-destroy-vs-dependent-delete-all) link to see the difference between `:delete_all` and `:destroy`.

```
class TableA < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :tablebs, :dependent => :delete_all
end

class TableB < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :tablea
end
```

Comment: actually i am using the table name in singular format..
sorry i missed it in the question.. updating it now..

Comment: also `deleteall`should be `delete_all`

Comment: Yeah i updated it.. actually i was posting a sample.
But in my actual example it was delete_all, and belongs_to entity in singular as you have mentioned

Comment: have you included the column tablea_id in the tableb? Please include your migration files in your question... it will help to understand the problem..