# Unable to delete model with nested children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: bars, dependent: :destroy
  has_one: roo, dependent: :destroy
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: bazs, dependent: :destroy
end

class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Roo < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I am trying to remove `Foo` with the following code, but I am getting an FK exception while removing baz references from bar/

Is my syntax for removing `roo` correct?

```
Foo.delete(foo_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@foo = Foo.find(foo_id)
@foo.destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

Ref [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2797382/297087) to understand the use of the `dependent: :destroy`, `destroy` & `delete`, so you have to use destroy method `:destroy/:destroy_all` The associated objects are destroyed alongside this object

```
@foo.destroy
```