# Deletion with has_and_belongs_to_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models, Note and Group, with has_and_belongs_to_many relations. Many notes can be in one group, one note can belong to many groups.

How can i delete all notes belongs to only one group?

UPD:

Thanks, but i don't want to delete all notes in group. I want to delete notes, that belongs **only to one** group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate your group, then call `clear` on the association.

```
@group.notes.clear
```

Here's the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many).

Comment: Will it delete all notes in specified group? Or it will delete only notes, belongs **only** to this group?

Comment: Uh, what? It will disassociate all notes belonging to the group `@group`. It does not destroy the notes, just removes the association with `@group`. To destroy the notes, do `@group.notes.destroy_all`.

Comment: Other words, let there are: groups 123 and 456, notes 111, 222, 333. Each note belongs to **both** groups. So, will Group.find(123).notes.destroy_all any notes?

Comment: `#destroy_all` will destroy the notes (from both groups). `#clear` will remove the notes from group 123, but not group 456. If you then `#clear` those notes from group 456, you will have orphaned notes (not associated with any group).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
@group.notes.destroy_all
```

OR

```
@group.notes.delete
```

Answer (score 1):

See the following stackoverflow question and answer regarding destroying associated data; in addition there is a plugin to protect some of your associations from being destroyed, I have used this plugin successfully on rails 2.x but have not tried it on rails 3.x

[Rails :dependent => :destroy VS :dependent => :delete_all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797339/rails-dependent-destroy-vs-dependent-delete-all)

:protect plugin --> http://ruido-blanco.net/blog/rails-dependent-protect-plugin-english/