# Rails associations and deletion

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, associations

I was going through Rails association  [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/association_basics.html). But I am not able to understand how the association works. I am using mysql db.

These are the files I generated:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
end
```

**order.rb**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**20150911181301_create_orders.rb**

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**20150911181351_create_users.rb**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

First I was expecting db:migrate will generate some foreign key relationship itself but it did not happen. Then I thought may be rails manages it internally but when I deleted a user through `rails c` , it did not delete corresponding orders from the order table.

Where is my understanding incorrect? Also give me some links which explains how does this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's debatable but the traditional 'Rails way' is to manage model-related things like defaults, foreign keys, and triggers is at the ActiveRecord level instead of in the database.

That said, you're free to add a foreign key for referential integrity in a migration using the following:

```
add_foreign_key :orders, :users
```

More information is available in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

The 'Rails way' to automatically destroy child objects when the parent is destroyed is to specify the `:dependent` strategy on the child collection. There is a great Stackoverflow discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797339/rails-dependent-destroy-vs-dependent-delete-all) going into detail about the two `:dependent`options: `:destroy` vs `:delete_all`.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is in the docs

-You should note that "**In any case, Rails will not create foreign key columns for you**. You need to explicitly define them as part of your migrations."

-You should also note that when it comes to associations, Rails needs you to tell it that asides two models being related with `belongs_to` and `has_many`, you want the associated model to be deleted when it's parent model is deleted. That is where the `dependent: :destroy` comes in.

Now all you need to do in your code for `orders` related to a user to get deleted when the user is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Source: [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)