# How to delete all the associations of a model when deleting it in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, model, associations

I have 3 models in my project. User, Meal & Food.
A user has many meals. A meal can have many food items and a food item can be a part of many meals.
The user and the meal model are in a has_many association, while the meal and the food model are in a has_many :through association. The join model for the meal and the food model is called MealFood.

When deleting the user I have made it so that it deletes all of the meals that belong to the user. However I can't make it so that it also deletes all the associations of the meal that belong to the user.

I need to delete every record in the meal_foods table where the meal_id belongs to the user that is being deleted.

**User Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :meals, :dependent => :delete_all
end
```

**Meal Model**

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
    has_many :meal_foods, :dependent => :delete_all
    has_many :foods, through: :meal_foods
end
```

**Food Model**

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :meal_foods
    has_many :meals, through: :meal_foods
end
```

**MealFood Model**

```
class MealFood < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :meal
  belongs_to :food
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `dependent: :destroy`, not `dependent: :delete_all`. `:delete_all` won't run callbacks and that's likely why your deeper associations remain persisted.

See the docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html):

> For `has_many`, `destroy` and `destroy_all` will always call the destroy
>   method of the record(s) being removed so that callbacks are run.
>   However `delete` and `delete_all` will either do the deletion according to
>   the strategy specified by the `:dependent` option, or if no `:dependent`
>   option is given, then it will follow the default strategy. The default
>   strategy is to do nothing (leave the foreign keys with the parent ids
>   set), except for `has_many :through`, where the default strategy is
>   `delete_all` (delete the join records, without running their callbacks).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797339/rails-dependent-destroy-vs-dependent-delete-all) thread has better answers.

Comment: Do you mean `dependent: :destroy`, not `dependent :destroy_all`, because I get this error `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end has_many :meals, :dependent :destroy_all `

Comment: Thank you it worked! Since I'm using devise I had a problem when deleting it, but it turns out that it's because I'm using a join model that doesn't have an id column. Just saying if someone has the same issue, just add a primary key to your join table!